# List comprehension correct format to include extended expression

Tags: python

I ma trying to iterate through a list of numbers to calculate the largest number, using list comprehension, but the syntax seems to be evading me. Precisely, I am not able to figure out where to place the expression. I am trying to use a counter, and store the largest number of the list in the counter. Is there a problem in my approach? Any help would be much appreciated. I have gone through a lot of questions concerning list comprehension but I have not been able to locate a working syntax to place the expression in list comprehension.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,722,4,35,353,5,4634,64,64,634,4,3]
counter= 0
b = [counter = num for num in a if num > counter]
print(b)
```

I am not able to figure out how to utilize the expression. I used this code block to capture the largest number in the list using a counter variable and for loop. What could be the working syntax to write this using list comprehension?

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,722,4,35,353,5,4634,64,64,634,4,3]
counter = 0 
for number in a:
    if number > counter:
        counter = number
print(counter)
```

Comment: Why not just do `max(a)`?

Comment: You don't want a list, so don't use a list comprehension.

Comment: alternatively: sort the list, then get the first/last element

Comment: Thankyou for the clarifications and alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions are not built for this. You can make something work by using a helper function and a global variable. The result is a list of maxima so far. The last element is the global max.

```
result = float('-inf')

def check(n):
    global result
    if result < n:
        result = n
        return True
    else:
        return False

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,722,4,35,353,5,4634,64,64,634,4,3]
b = [x for x in a if check(x)]

print(b)
```

This prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 722, 4634]
```

Comment: Bah, global. And so complicated. If that list were what they wanted, all they'd have to do is to add a single `:` in their list comprehension.

Answer (score -1):

Easy way is to **sort** a/the list in place.

Example in phyton:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,722,4,35,353,5,4634,64,64,634,4,3]
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 35, 64, 64, 353, 634, 722, 4634]
>>> a[-1]
4634
>>> b = sorted(a, reverse=True)
>>> b
[4634, 722, 634, 353, 64, 64, 35, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1]
>>> b[0]
4634
```